# newly setup Apache server giving incorrect Content-Length header for .png and .swf

Tags: apache-2.2

Perhaps I'm missing some necessary module or bit of configuration. Set this server up a few days ago, Apache 2, Ubuntu 10.04. Put a site up on it. Visit the site, notice that the bottom edges of .png images are sliced off. Also, the last little bit of a flash animation didn't seem to run.

The files on the server's filesystem appear to be intact -- the bottom edges of the .pngs do not appear sliced-off if I grab the file via SCP. But they do in the browser or when grabbed with wget.

Comparing with the same files served up from on a different server, I noticed that on the .png and .swf files, the new server is sending a somewhat smaller number in the Content-Length header. I figure this is where the problem is, but don't know what would be causing this or what to do about it.

Comment: Is the data being compressed by Apache?  Verify that the `Content-Length` is still wrong when compression is not involved.

Comment: I think Deflate is being used. If my company had a real server-admin instead of my developer self, I wouldn't have to ask, but: how do I turn off said compression?

Comment: On Ubuntu, `a2dismod deflate`.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that and get back. Incidentally the two servers mentioned above, as far as I could see there was no difference between their deflate.conf files.

Comment: After disabling deflate & restarting apache, the Content-Length header is the same and the images still look mangled. :(

Comment: sorry, to clarify, the Content-Length is the same incorrect value as it was before disabling deflate.

Comment: What's the network topology look like between your system and the server?  A misbehaving device may be breaking the connection, or it could be an issue with Apache itself; try `EnableSendfile Off` and `EnableMMAP Off` and check out Apache's error logs?

Comment: EnableMMAP Off and EnableSendfile Off likewise have no effect. will take a look at error logs.

Comment: Error log for this particular vhost is empty. Default error log shows little of interest -- just some deprecation warnings from RubyGems, or, when delate is disabled, the error message "an unknown filter was not added: DEFLATE"

Comment: Well here it is folks... apparently these files were being served up via the Rails app through a Metal thing (for some reason that I don't fully understand, the app greatly predates my involvement with it). The discrepancy in Content-Lengths was due to having Ruby 1.8.7 (actually REE) on the server where it worked correctly versus 1.9 on the new server and this Metal thing setting the Content-Length based on the value returned by #length called on the file contents --

Comment: it was giving a length in "characters" rather than bytes, interpreting certain byte combinations as multibyte characters. Having it read the file in binary mode straightened it out.

Answer (score 0):

From the [comments](https://serverfault.com/questions/313056/newly-setup-apache-server-giving-incorrect-content-length-header-for-png-and-s#comment301737_313056)

Well here it is folks... apparently these files were being served up via the Rails app through a Metal thing (for some reason that I don't fully understand, the app greatly predates my involvement with it). The discrepancy in Content-Lengths was due to having Ruby 1.8.7 (actually REE) on the server where it worked correctly versus 1.9 on the new server and this Metal thing setting the Content-Length based on the value returned by #length called on the file contents